# Why is it so much faster passing an array as a literal rather than a parameter?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT
   table1.field1,
   table1.field2,
   table3.field1,
   table3.field2,
   table3.field3,
   table3.field4

FROM table1

INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.field1 = table2.field1

INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.field2 = table3.field5

WHERE table1.field1 = ANY(@pArray);
```

All of these comparisons are with string/text fields. There are indexes on all of the foreign key fields. This is a poorly designed database that I have mostly just read-only access to.

What I'm wondering is why the above parameter causes this query to take 10+ seconds, whereas if I pass the array manually as an array literal (using string concatenation), then it takes about 40-50 milliseconds.

My array contains 195 8-character numeric string elements.

My only guess is that it has something to do with sanitizing the parameter values, but making the query take hundreds of times longer seems a bit excessive. What I've done is add my own check to make sure that all of the strings are 100% numeric, which I think should avoid SQL injection attacks.

My NpgSql code looks like this:

```cs
void MyQuery(
   string[] pArray
) {
   var sql = @"
      // as above
   ";

   using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(mConnectionString);
   connection.Open();

   using var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pArray", pArray);

   // takes ~12 seconds with parameter, or ~50ms with array literal
   using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

When removing the parameter, the `WHERE` clause ends up looking more like this, after concating:

```
WHERE table1.field1 = ANY('{12345678,12345679,12345680,12345681}');
```

Is the slowness due only to sanitization, or a bug in NpgSql, or something else?

Comment: `AddWithValue` doesn't guarantee correct type match in DB engine. Use `Add(parameter)`, with `Parameter.DbType` or Provider -specific db type. When parameter type is wrong, DB start to implicitly convert it and this can cancel indexes.

Comment: @T.S. specifying the `NpgsqlDbType` as `NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Char` fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as indicated in the comments was adding a parameter without specifying the type. Changing the parameter line to the following solved the problem:

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("pArray", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Char, pArray);
```

Notice that to specify an array type, you OR the `Array` value with another value, in this case `Char`. The actual PostgreSQL type in the database is something like `character varying(15)`.

Comment: To add a bit more context, Npgsql does automatically infer parameter types with NpgsqlDbType - but strings are inferred as `text`, not `varchar`. Thus a `string[]` is inferred to be a PG `text[]`, which is not what you have in the database - this causes the implicit cast and prevents index usage. If your database column were a `text[]` everything would work well without NpgsqlDbType.

Comment: I looked into documentation. There is not such overload as you posted. Best fit is `AddWithValue(String, NpgsqlDbType, Object)`